# Trying to parse list in loops

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a basic list as follows

```
data = "ffff,999,John Doe, Sam Adams"
mydata = data.split(',')
```

I want to be able to check if the 4th field is not null and if it is set a variable to the 4th field else set the variable to the 3rd field.

I have the following code

```
if mydata[3] is not None:
    name = mydata[3]
elif mydata[2] is not None:
    name = mydata[2]
```

The first part works, but if I set data to

```
data = "ffff,999,John Doe,"
```

The code doesn't do anything. What am I doing wrong?
Thanks

Comment: `mydata[3] is not None` will still return `True` if `mydata[3]` just happens to be empty. replace with `mydata[3].strip() != ''` or even simpler, `mydata[3].strip()` already returns `False`

Answer (score 0):

Since you split on ',' and data has trailing comma, your last item in `lst` is an empty string

```
>>> data = "ffff,999,John Doe,"
>>>
>>> data.split(',')
['ffff', '999', 'John Doe', '']
>>> lst = data.split(',')
>>>
>>> lst[3] is not None
True
```

This is how `split()` behaves.

[Python2.7 str.split()](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=split#str.split)